# How does application install size vary on phone?

Tags: android, animation, view, dialog, size

I recently made this [**application**](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.torcellite.powerbutton) for root users who mod their device frequently.

Now I noticed quite strange behaviour with the application's install size.

When I used a regular activity with views being initialized from the XML file, the size was `715 kb`.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    executeEvents = new ExecuteEvents(this);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    powermenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.powermenu);
    turnoffscreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.turnscreenoff);
    mapButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mapButton);
    SP = getSharedPreferences(PBConstants.Power_Button_SP, MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    if(SP.contains(PBConstants.INPUT_DEVICE_TAG))
        display.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.configured));
    mapButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    powermenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    turnoffscreen.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

After I switched to a dialog which was created setting a view which contained the widgets in the XML file. The app size was now `200kb`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, null);
    executeEvents = new ExecuteEvents(this);
    display = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.display);
    powermenu = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.powermenu);
    turnoffscreen = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.turnscreenoff);
    mapButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.mapButton);
    SP = getSharedPreferences(PBConstants.Power_Button_SP, MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    if(SP.contains(PBConstants.INPUT_DEVICE_TAG))
        display.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.configured));
    mapButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    powermenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    turnoffscreen.setOnClickListener(this);

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    dialog.show();
}
```

It reduced to `80kb` when I used this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    executeEvents = new ExecuteEvents(this);
    display = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.display);
    powermenu = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.powermenu);
    turnoffscreen = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.turnscreenoff);
    mapButton = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mapButton);
    SP = getSharedPreferences(PBConstants.Power_Button_SP, MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    if(SP.contains(PBConstants.INPUT_DEVICE_TAG))
        display.setText(getString(R.string.configured));
    mapButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    powermenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    turnoffscreen.setOnClickListener(this);
    dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    dialog.show();
    dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
}
```

I also noticed another strange change in application size when I tried to add an animation with the last style of code(the `80kb` one). The app size became a hefty `1 MB`. This is how I initialized the animation and tried calling it when the button was clicked :

```
private static final ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(1, .95f, 1, .95f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);//declared as global variable
```

Inside the onCreate method:

```
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(false);
```

After which I called it in the `onClickListener`:

```
mapButton.startAnimation(animation);
```

Why is there such a drastic change in application size when I haven't added any new resources but only changed the style of code? Where is there such a HUGE difference in the way I initialize widgets present in dialogs? Why is there a HUGE difference when I add an animation the way I've added it?

**Follow up question:**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    executeEvents = new ExecuteEvents(this);
    display = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.display);
    powermenu = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.powermenu);
    turnoffscreen = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.turnscreenoff);
    mapButton = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.mapButton);
    SP = getSharedPreferences(PBConstants.Power_Button_SP, MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    if(SP.contains(PBConstants.INPUT_DEVICE_TAG))
        display.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.configured));
    mapButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    powermenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    turnoffscreen.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

**SPECULATION**

Could this be due to the packages or classes which are imported? It makes sense for the `animation` bit of the question at least.

Would adding the context to which the views are initialized reduce memory usage?

Comment: You can unzip your APK and analyze its components. You can also dissect the dex file (http://code.google.com/p/smali) to see its structure.

Comment: The size of the APK is same. The installation size is different.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. On a rooted device you can analyze the individual files that are related to an installed application, though. Like, `ls -l /data/app/{package}`, `ls -l /data/data/{package}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yup, your speculations are close to be right, so as you may know all your Java code first is compiled to Java bytecode by say `javac`, then `dx` converts them to Dalvik bytecode, your dalvik bytecode file (a.k.a. `dex`) is packaged inside your apk (btw apk size doesn't vary much as zip compression helps) usually as `classes.dex` which later on when you install the apk in you device, Android might optimize it for that particular device (a.k.a. `odex`).

So to verify that your final cached `dex` actually changes and is the responsible for this size change, by say just adding animations, you can find it either by unzipping your apk or inside your device, I always find the second option more exciting:

So here is your `dex` without animation (your `80kb`):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZYcH.png]

And your app info:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/htFOc.png]

So here is your `dex` with animation (your `1 MB`):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0XNa.png]

And your app info:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mLat.png]

A closer look you can find they are truly different by just looking right in your dalvik bytecode constants pool:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8RXj.png]

For some reason I didn't get such radical size difference yet it is noticiable, I built your app using gradle + Android Studio so I think they help and optimize things a bit.

Finally, you could use ProGuard but hey! some k aren't that much this days, I wouldn't worry  for adding some "fat" to your app as long it makes it better, of course there is always room for improvement yet remember that you are not in a java4k or stuff like that :)

Comment: When you did perform these changes did the performance of the application vary with different styles of implementation?

Comment: @Torcellite that's another question, I'd say you should first worry about leaking `MainActivity`s with all those `static` members before even worrying about performance

Comment: I was under the impression that static members are allowed only one instance and thus don't cause much of a leak. Please pardon my ignorance on the subject. I'm trying to learn.

Comment: @Torcellite no worries, we're all just trying to learn :) just pointing out that I hope this answer fulfill your original question, regarding `static` I'd recommend you to read something about it, I love the Head First series and they just happen to have a pretty good book named Head First Java

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation and thanks for taking the pain to research so much. :) I'd like the bounty to run it's course though and see if any different answer pops up. If not, I shall award it to you.